# How to resolve Bad ComponentName while traversing activity parent metadata?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am writing an unit test for a class, which has call to `addParentStack(XActivity.class)`.  XActivity is declared at manifest and has

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="y.YActivity" />.
```

YActivity is under another module.
Code runs fine. But while running Unit test i am getting error as

> Bad ComponentName while traversing activity parent metadata

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: testclass/YActivity
```

So, what i have to do extra to run this unit test?